# How do I run different background jobs with Python Flask threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I have a python flask web application, in one of the functions `generator`, I need to do some deep learning jobs in a ssh server, and it will take few minutes to finish. However, in the meantime, in the same function, I want to extract images in a folder in the server. But it would not start reading the images until the deep learning is completed.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def generator():
    train() # a function for deep learning in the server
        
    # this code will not reach the 'while' loop until the train() finishes the job in the server.

    while True:
        # some other tasks here for reading images in a folder in the server

@app.route('/abc')
def abc():
    return Response(generator(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

I heard a class in python called threading may do the jobs, but I am new to threading and do not know how to start? any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.